# Liquibase connection could not be created to Database

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, liquibase

Liquibase is unable to connect to the database, when I am running liquibase against my database, I get the following error:

```
liquibase_1  | Starting Liquibase at 21:40:22 (version 4.23.1 #12042 built at 2023-08-10 13:48+0000)
liquibase_1  | Liquibase Version: 4.23.1
liquibase_1  | Liquibase Open Source 4.23.1 by Liquibase
liquibase_1  | 
liquibase_1  | Unexpected error running Liquibase: Connection could not be created to jdbc:mysql://mysql_db:3307/patshala with driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver.  Communications link failure
liquibase_1  | 
liquibase_1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
liquibase_1  |   - Caused by: Connection refused
```

Below is my docker compose file, is there anything I am missing here?

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mysql_db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: patshala
      MYSQL_USER: mysql
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    networks:
      - app-network

  liquibase:
    image: liquibase/liquibase:latest
    command: ["--url=jdbc:mysql://mysql_db:3307/patshala", "--username=mysql", "--password=password", "--changeLogFile=/db/changelog/db.changelog.xml", "update"]
    volumes:
      - ./db:/liquibase/changelog
      - ./mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:/liquibase/lib/mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar
    depends_on:
      - mysql_db
    networks:
      - app-network


networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Answer (score 1):

```
volumes:
  - ./db:/liquibase/changelog
  - ./mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:/liquibase/lib/mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar
```

Based from the latest documentation of Liquibase, you need to create a Dockerfile in order to install the MySQL driver to Liquibase.

Reference: [MySQL Licensing Restriction](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/using-liquibase-and-docker.html#MySQL)

Answer (score 1):

You are exposing port `3307` to the host machine. Both liquibase and mysql are in the same network `app-network` so if you use port 3307, liquibase could not connect to it. So:

- Try to change to port 3306
- If still persists, make sure mysql is up and running (checking log and maybe connecting from your host machine)